# Performance Problems With Stack Overflow

Tags: support, firefox, gravatar, performance

Not sure where the issue lies, but tonight I have received red connect failed dialogs when trying to show additional comments or when checking my inbox to select new comments. Simply refreshing the top questions list is also affected.

I don't know if this is related, but several times I see "Performing TLS handshake with www.gravatar.com" stuck in the URL display at the bottom of Firefox.

Just thought I would pass it along if you haven't had indication from your server logs yet.

**Example**

Just clicking "Review your Question" here took 43 seconds to show the actual question.

Browser: openSUSE 15.4, with Firefox 91.9.0esr.

Comment: What browser (version) and OS are you using? Any adblockers or other extensions? Did you try with a different network / device? Where in the world are you, roughly? Which ISP are you using?

Comment: openSUSE 15.4, with Firefox 91.9.0esr. Yes NOAA National Weather Service RADAR maps are without any delay (surprising given the load on their system tonight) I'm in that increasingly strange place called Texas.

Comment: I doubt SE can resolve issues that involve TLS handshakes with 3rd party sites, as in: the error is likely on a network path not under control anywhere by SE. The only option would be for SE to stop allowing users upload Gravatar profile images. Which might be a good call.

Comment: Not sure it is the gravatar.com site, that's just the URL stuck in the firefox display (which could be the last successful operation before the hang occurs). Like I said, I'm just passing this along in case you have an issue growing somewhere (may not). SO is just not that usable tonight from where I am and I experienced the same filing this question here.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. Gravatar is a red-herring tough. But I won't rule out Texas is the problem ;)

Comment: Blame it on Governor Hot-Wheels...

Comment: No repro for me tonight, either on Chrome or Firefox. I also (currently) live in that increasingly strange place called Texas.

Comment: I wouldn't rule out it being a rural East Texas problem -- though my daughter is playing Valarant and not complaining about ping issues -- so our general internet is working fine `:)` The issue is also highly intermittent, I'll go for 3-4 minutes with no issue, then 3-4 minutes of "waiting on gravatar.com" messages. If your logs are good, then just checking accomplished the purpose of the question and this can be closed -- we will see how it does tomorrow.

Comment: To be clear, I'm a mod, not a Stack Overflow developer. I don't have access to any logs other than the ones on my own machines.